# Android Changing Toolbar Based on Navigation View Selection

Tags: android, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

I have an activity named as  **MainActivity.java**  , in this I have implemented a navigation view based on   **DrawerLayout**

Here is the `XML` code of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**In the navigation view I have 4 options. Following is the output of the page**

[image]

Now following are things I need to do
1. Instead of the word   **MainActivity**   I need to show an Image which contains the text related to my app.

2. Initially when the activity is loaded I don't want to show the search icon at top right corner.
3. In the navigation view when I select 2nd option I need to show the search icon and when I select 3rd option I need to show a + button instead of search icon.

How to implement all the above by customizing the   **ToolBar** .

Answer (score 0):

```
    Here you can do the following

    1. Instead of the word MainActivity i need to show an image which contains the text related to my app.
    You can customise the toolbar by creating a custom toolbar and placing the image which you want to show.

toolbar.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


       <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_screens_toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

For 2 & 3 :
Here you can get the reference of the search and plus icon,by which you can hide and show them simultaneously.
getActivity().findByViewId() inside the fragment.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

create customtoolbar.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Right Menu"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

include this customtoolbar.xml file under AppBarLayout Tag

In MainActivity

```
NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                selectDrwerMenu(menuItem);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

// main logic here

```
 private void selectDrwerMenu(MenuItem menu) {
        switch (menu.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.first:
                //change or add image to toolbar imageview
                break;
            case R.id.second:

                //show toolbar right side image
                break;
            case R.id.third:

                break;
            default:
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    }
```

and please replace actionbar with toolbar in MainActivity
for this http://mrengineer13.com/how-to-use-toolbar-to-replace-your-actionbar/